# How to loop through hierarchy from CSV file?

Tags: powershell

Given the following CSV file, how do I loop through it correctly? Do I need some sort of hashtable?

CSV file:

```
AD/Profile Name,Org Level,Org Member
AD_Group1,Region,"China
USA"
AD_Group2,Sub Region,"China
Corp"
AD_Group3,Sub Region,USA
```

Code:

```
$clmns = Import-Csv .\File1.csv

foreach ($ADGroup in $clmns.'AD/Profile Name') {
    $ADGroup
    foreach ($orglvl in $ADGroup.'Org Level') {
    $orglvl
    
        foreach ($orgmember in $orglvl.'Org Member') {
            $orgmember
            
        }
    }
}
```

`$orglvl` and `$orgmember` aren't printing out anything when I'm running this.

Expected result:

```
AD_Group1
Region
China
USA
AD_Group2
Sub Region
China
Corp
AD_Group3
Sub Region
USA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7) should be able to handle this task:

```
$clmns = Import-Csv .\File1.csv
$clmns | Group-Object -Property 'Org Level' | Foreach-Object {
    $_.Name
    $_.Group.'Org Member'
}
```

The `Name` property will be the `Org Level` values that are iterated. Grouped objects are accessed through the `Group` property.

**Edit 1:**

Based on your updated post, you only need one loop to list all the values:

```
$clmns = Import-Csv .\File1.csv
foreach ($row in $clmns) {
    $row.'ad/profile name'
    $row.'org level'
    $row.'org member'
}
```

**Edit 2:**

I read your post from the powershell.org site. You can do the following to accomplish the task. I am assuming `$table` contains an array of custom objects already.

```
$clmns = Import-Csv .\File1.csv
foreach ($row in $clmns) {
    $ADGroup = $row.'AD/Profile Name'
    $OrgLevel = $row.'Org Level'
    $data = $table | Where {$_.$OrgLevel -in ($row.'Org Member' -split '\r?\n') }
    [pscustomobject]@{'AD Group' = $ADGroup; 'Org Codes' = "{0}|" -f ($data.'Org Code' -join '|')}
}
```

Comment: oh wow thats so simple and awesome :D one thing however is that it appears that it combines the 3rd level with the 2nd level. for example, i am getting the following displayed for Sub Region: China
Corp
USA, shouldnt it be Sub Region: China Corp and then again Sub Region: USA?

Comment: @Cataster, I don't see that issue. I see them separately. However, fixed your file by not having the extra line breaks as posted. I assumed those were posted in error. I apologize if not, but I don't understand them if they are necessary.

Comment: i think the line breaks are intentional. at least tahts how i see it in notepad++. for example, if i run user3898488 code below with the csv info i have posted, i get the correct output

Comment: essentially, i'd also like the AD Profile to be identified in the output as well. maybe that will fix the output with this approach?

Comment: @Cataster can you post an example of your ideal output in your post?

Comment: @Cataster, I added a new edit with one loop. You only need to call the properties in order given this type of file schema.

Comment: wait but this doesnt form a hierarchy. like for example, if i want to index org member at specific org level, then it has to know that it falls under it, like a parent-child relationship...This is what im trying to do ultimately: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/how-to-create-access-a-hierarchy-of-keys-and-insert-delimited-values-from-a-csv/

Comment: @Cataster, I added a second edit to answer your post from powershell.org

Comment: Yes this seems to be the right approach. Note, $table would actually be a sql table, not a pscustom object table. I wonder, do you think itd be easier if I select everything from the sql OrgTable and store it in a $table pscustomobject instead of running a query to search for the Org Code? This is what I am doing currently: `$OrgCode = Query "SELECT [Org Code] FROM [dbo].[OrgTable] 
                        WHERE [$orglvl] = '$orglvl.value' AND [$orgmember] = '$orgmember.value'"
            Query "INSERT INTO [dbo].[NewTable] 
                (AD Group, Org Codes)”`

Comment: How many rows are in the sql table? If it is small, I’d read the whole thing into powershell

Comment: About 2000 rows

Comment: DUDE, this is awesome!! I just had to do this: `$table = Query "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[OrgTable]"` and Powershell automatically converted it to a psobject :D I LOVE powershell man! even python isnt that convenient LOL. btw, i am getting a result like this: `1098|123_KL|234G|f908L_P|m500_ABC|Z45557` this is great but what if i want a | also at the end even if theres no more org codes to list, meaning like this: `...m500_ABC|Z45557|`?

Comment: @Cataster, I updated Edit 2 to add the trailing `|`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
$clmns = Import-Csv "G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Test\File1.csv"

$clmns | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $orglvl = $_.'Org Level'
    $Members =  ($_.'Org Member').split("`r`n")
    "$($_.'AD/Profile Name')"
    For ($Cntr=0; $cntr -lt $Members.count; $Cntr+=2) { 
      "Member: $($Members[$($Cntr)]) `tLevel: $orglvl"
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
AD_Group1
Member: China   Level: Region
Member: USA     Level: Region
AD_Group2
Member: China   Level: Sub Region
Member: Corp    Level: Sub Region
AD_Group3
Member: USA     Level: Sub Region
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
foreach ($ADGroup in $clmns.'AD/Profile Name') {
    $tmp = $clmns | Where-Object {$_.'AD/Profile Name' -eq $ADGroup}

    foreach ($orglvl in $tmp.'Org Level') {
        $orglvl
        $tmp2 = $tmp  | Where-Object {$_.'Org Level' -eq $orglvl}
            foreach ($orgmember in $tmp2.'Org Member') {
                $orgmember

            }
            

    }
}
```

It might be a still a little bit buggy but I think you get the idea

Comment: yes this one definitely works as intended :) it was just missing a closing brace for outer loop

Comment: Wouls, yes youre right. I have fixed it in my answer